# A renewal theorem question

Tags: probability-theory, renewal-processes

Here's the question: on each round, Ann and Bob each simultaneously toss a fair coin. Let $X_n$ be the number of heads tossed in the $2n$ flips which occur during the first $n$ rounds. For each integer $m>0$, let $r_m$ denote the probability that there exists an $n$ such that $X_n = m$. Use a renewal theorem to find $\lim_{m\to\infty}r_m.$

My thought is, we can think of $X_n$ as summation of $n$ inter-arrival times of a renew process, each is independent and has mean 1; think of $m$ as a time point. Let $N(m)$ denote max number of hits (in this case each hit is 1 round of coin toss) before time $m$. We have $\lim_{m\to\infty} r_m = \lim_{m\to\infty} P(\exists \ n \ s.t. X_n = m) = \lim_{m\to\infty} P(\exists \ n \ s.t. X_n = m | N(m) = m-1)P(N(m) = m-1)+P(\exists \ n \ s.t. X_n = m | N(m) = m-2)P(N(m)=m-2) = \lim_{m\to\infty} \frac{1}{2} P(N(m) = m-1) + \frac{1}{4}P(N(m)=m-2).$

This is where I got stuck. Now by renew theorem, we have: $\lim_{m\to\infty} \frac{X_{N(m)}}{m} = \lim_{m\to\infty}\frac{X_{N(m)}}{N(m)}\frac{N(m)}{m} = 1 \ w.p.1$. Does this mean $\lim_{m\to\infty} P(\frac{X_{N(m)}}{m-1} = 1) = \lim_{m\to\infty} P(\frac{X_{N(m)}}{m-2} =1) = 1?$ This doesn't make intuitive sense to me since $X_{N(m)}$ can either be $m-1$ or $m-2$, and the two probabilities should sum up to 1, not each equal to 1. Any help on how to proceed is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What does something like $P(\frac{X_{N(m)}}{m-1})$ mean?

Comment: Sorry my bad! It’s a typo, just corrected it.

Comment: If your question is just where you are stuck, then by definition, $\lim_{m\to\infty} \frac{X_{N(m)}}{m} = 1$ with probability $1$ means $P\left(\lim_{m\to\infty} \frac{X_{N(m)}}{m} = 1\right) = 1$.  Putting the limit outside the probability as you have done makes it a significantly stronger statement which is false.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to apply the renewal theorem to solve this problem (I tried), but you can certainly solve it using a recurrence relation.

Take $A_m$ as the event that $X_1+\dots+X_n=m$ for some $n\geq 1$. Conditioning on $X_1$ yields $$\begin{eqnarray*}r_1 &=& \mathbb{P}(A_1) \\ &=& \frac{1}{4}\mathbb{P}(A_1|X_1=0)+\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{P}(A_1|X_1=1)+\frac{1}{4}\mathbb{P}(A_1|X_1=2) 
 \\ &=& \frac{1}{4}\mathbb{P}(A_1)+ \frac{1}{2} \cdot 1 + \frac{1}{4}\cdot 0 \\&=& \frac{r_1}{4}+\frac{1}{2}\end{eqnarray*}$$ Solving for $r_1$ yields $r_1=\frac{2}{3}$. Similarly, $$\begin{eqnarray*}r_2 &=& \mathbb{P}(A_2) \\ &=& \frac{1}{4}\mathbb{P}(A_2|X_1=0)+\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{P}(A_2|X_1=1)+\frac{1}{4}\mathbb{P}(A_2|X_1=2) \\&=& \frac{1}{4}\mathbb{P}(A_2)+\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{P}(A_1)+\frac{1}{4}\cdot 1 \\ &=& \frac{r_2}{4}+\frac{r_1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}\end{eqnarray*}$$ Solve for $r_2$ and get $r_2=\frac{7}{9}$. Since $\mathbb{P}(A_m|X_1=j)=r_{m-j}$ for $m\geq 3$ and $j\in \{0,1,2\}$ we get $$\begin{eqnarray*}r_m&=& \mathbb{P}(A_m) \\ &=& \frac{1}{4}\mathbb{P}(A_m|X_1=0)+\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{P}(A_m|X_1=1)+\frac{1}{4}\mathbb{P}(A_m|X_1=2) \\ &=& \frac{r_m}{4}+\frac{r_{m-1}}{2}+\frac{r_{m-2}}{4}\end{eqnarray*}$$ This unveils the recurrence relation $$r_m=\frac{2}{3}r_{m-1}+\frac{1}{3}r_{m-2};r_1=\frac{2}{3},r_2=\frac{7}{9}$$ which has unique solution $$r_m=\frac{1}{4}\left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)^m+\frac{3}{4}$$ Taking $m\mapsto +\infty$ gives a limit of $\frac{3}{4}$. I would be very interested to see an approach using a renewal theorem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think I understand what’s happening now. From my approach, if I take the limit w.r.t. $m$, the two probability terms do go to 1 and I’m ending up with the same answer as yours. I think renew theorem gives almost sure converge statement, which allows us to pull the limit outside to form convergence in probability statement. Also, the statement is the two probability terms both have limiting probability of 1, which could happen.

Comment: I'm happy as long as you understand why the limit is $3/4$. I have to admit I'm not that familiar with renewal theory, but this problem has inspired me to do some research on the subject, and it looks fascinating.

Comment: Glad to hear it! Yeah it’s very helpful sometimes